# scrapy selenium login then search pages

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

I'm wrapping up a project to learn more about scrapy and selenium, I'm very new to scrapy and python in general.

I'm trying to scrape grocery.walmart.com in an effort to check prices on local grocery items. grocery.walmart.com requires either a zipcode or a login. When I attempt to use the form request scraper I typically get a valueerror that it cannot find the form. I've attempted to follow the documentation and some of the various websites but to no avail. If you attempt to go directly to the URL of an item the page will not load as it needs either a login or a zipcode but I cant find a way to pass a zipcode in, so it appears it requires that you go to the first page, enter a zipcode then continue thru the website. Is it possible to go to the zipcode/login page then pass in url's for specific items while keeping myself logged in or a zipcode passed in?

I've added my spider below:

```
class GrocerySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "Grocery"
    allowed_domains = ["walmart.com"]
    with open("grocery.txt", "rt") as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

def __init__(self):
    scrapy.Spider.__init__(self)
    self.br = webdriver.Chrome()

def _del_(self):
    self.br.close()

def parse(self, response):
    yield scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
        response,
        formxpath = '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/form',
        formdata={'postalCode': '12345'},
        clickdata = {"type" : "Submit" },
        callback=self.after_login
    )       

def after_login(self, response): 
    self.br.get(response.url)
    time.sleep(5)
    Today = datetime.datetime.now()
    br_selector = Selector(text = self.br.page_source)
    grocload = ProductLoader(item=WmtGroc(), selector=br_selector)
    grocload.add_xpath("title", "//h1[@class'_2_SmE355ZdP4Ymmg7ew7RT']/text()")
```

Any help would be appreciated, I feel as if this has to be possible but I'm struggling to find documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can open the url by adding `self.br.add_cookie({'': ''})` with your login information before `self.br.get(response.url)` , or you can finish all the process in parse() that you should login by selenium directly, using code like 
the example:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('usernameField').send_keys('xxx')
driver.find_element_by_id('passwordField').send_keys('xxxxx')
driver.find_element_by_id('SubmitButton').click()
```

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response but thanks so much the second option solved my problem. So for the url I hard coded the login page and then the pertinent login data as shown above and boom works like a charm. Thanks for your help!